# Angular 2: Binding a response value to a input type in loop ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing issue in binding the response values to input type text in a ngFor loop.

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of items">
     <input type="text"  class="form-control" #inputTarget>
  <div>
```

if I bind, all the text box binding same values. how should bind different item values to each text box

Comment: (1) Are the `items` string variables? (2) Are these controls inside of a `form` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `attribute binding`, `[value]="item"`

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of items">
     <input type="text"  class="form-control" #inputTarget [value]="item">
<div>
```

**The above code takes the `item` and assigns to `value` of the text box**

[**Here is a small DEMO for the same**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GLXBvD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `[value]` item

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of items">
     <input type="text"  [value]="item" class="form-control" #inputTarget>
<div>
```